# Mocking function within a function pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pytest

```
def func1():
    return 5
    
def func2(param1, param2):
    
    var1 = func1()
    return param1 + param2 + var1
```

I want to use pytest to test the second function by mocking the first, but I am not sure how to do this.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_func1(self):
    with mock.patch(
        "func1",
        return_value= 5,
    ) as self.mock_func1:
        yield
```

I think it can be done with a dependency injection and fixture as above but that would mean changing func1 which I would prefer not to do.

Comment: If those functions are in the same module, as shown, don't mock anything - that's an implementation detail. Assert on the overall return of `func2`, e.g. `assert func2(2, 2) == 9`. That way you can refactor confidently within the module boundary and your tests remain useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to change anything.

You can use `mocker` fixture with `pytest` (requires installation of [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/)). don't worry about the `mocker` argument, it will magically work.

```
def test_func2(mocker):
    mocked_value = 4
    first = 1
    second = 2
    func1_mock = mocker.patch("func1")
    func1_mock.return_value = mocked_value
    actual_value = func2(first, second)
    assert actual_value == first + second + mocked_value
```

Comment: I was not aware of pytest-mock thanks !